# Asp.net mvc 3: Strange Validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have applied DataAnnotation based validations to two of my properties like this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Here is the view page's code

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Obj.Title)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Obj.Title)            

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Obj.Description)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Obj.Description)
```

The Problem is that on click of submit button, on client side (js) its only giving me error for for Title and not for the Description. But Its giving me validation error for the Description after the postback.

What possible causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, that's weird. Unable to repro.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MainViewModel { Obj = new MyViewModel() });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.MainViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Obj.Title)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Obj.Title)            

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Obj.Description)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Obj.Description)  
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Client and server validation work fine.

Comment: I have just checked the generated html output of mine. Found that for textarea there is no atrribute data-val="true". But for textbox it has data-val="true". Can you please confirm yours?

Comment: @coure06, I get correctly a `data-val="true"` on the textarea with the sample code I have shown.

Comment: any idea when it does not generate data-val?

Comment: @coure06, I can't see any form inside your view. Is there a `@Html.BeginForm()` somewhere? Without a form, no validation attributes are generated.

Comment: here is the completely updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925072/asp-net-mvc3-validation-mystry